# How to read a json file as a dictionary in Databricks

Tags: json, apache-spark, databricks

Can anybody help me read a json file as a dictionary in databricks and not a dataframe? When I read it using the following it becomes a spark dataframe:

```
spark.read.format("json").load(path_to_json)
```

and I cant get the following to work on databricks either, because it needs an aws secret key:

```
import boto3
import json
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY={{secrets/scope/aws_secret_access_key}}
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID={{secrets/scope/aws_access_key_id}}
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_ID, aws_secret_access_key= ACCESS_KEY)
obj = s3.Object('slm-transaction-incoming','All_Starbucks_Locations_in_the_US.json')
string = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

json = json.loads(string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since loading path via Spark works for you, it means that this path is mounted in DBFS.

But DBFS filesystem (`dbfs:`) is also accessible under `/dbfs` for all non-Spark commands. This in turn means that you can directly access this file.

```
raw_path_to_json = path_to_json.replace("dbfs:", "/dbfs")
with open(raw_path_to_json, 'r') as f:
    string = f.read()
json = json.loads(string)
```

Comment: I tried this. The with open line gives the following error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
The path is /Fileshare/tables not dbfs